# absolute positioned element has wrong offsetWidth for content past right side of browser window

Tags: javascript, css, html, position

I have an absolute positioned div *(think tooltip)* that is moved to specific positions. When it is positioned near the right edge of the browser window and the html content is wider than the visible width of the div, `offsetWidth` returns a value that: is `window.width - div.style.left` instead of the real width. In other words it is as though the content is clipped.

The div uses `visibility: hidden` and `overflow: visible`. If I check `offsetWidth` after setting `visibility: visible;` it is still wrong.

I've also checked `scrollWidth` and  `getBoundingClientRect()` and they are wrong. I'm not using jQuery but did check `.outerWidth()` and it was also wrong.

If I reset the div position: `div.style.left = div.style.top = '0px';` and then check `offsetWidth` it gives the correct width.

This happens on both Chrome and Firefox. I'm at a loss as to what's going on here.

Comment: Does it still have an incorrect width if you set `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Yes it is still incorrect.